# Vscode run build task not working... it begins but never ends

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, wsl-2, vscode-tasks

i have a problem with build function in vscode (language C) because when i click on "run build task", "debug C/C++ file" or "Run C/C++ file" vscode starts building my active file but never ends. So debugger does not work at all.

Windows: 11
Vscode: 1.83.1
WSL: 2

I found out that folder ".vscode" does not work as should also

Run code       - works (it shows me output and everything)
Run C/C++ file - does not work

(It does not work without wsl anyway)

[This is what happens when it starts building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1tvq.png)
[Bottom pallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et97r.png)

I have installed gcc and gdb
I proceeded according to instructions as i found on Microsoft website
At the beginning i use it withou wsl and i needed to instal msys2 for gcc (just for info if it helps)

Comment: What do you mean by  _folder ".vscode" does not work_?

Comment: when i click build it should create 3 json files in .vscode but in my case it create only task.json or nothing

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to create those 3 files in the `.vscode` folder (I could be wrong tho), but you can create them manually with the configurations you want. Also if you are using WSL then it'd have a different compiler and GDB so make sure to point those out in `c_cpp_properties.json` and `launch.json`.